# Copy/paste 1 column, dynamic range, into separate worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking to copy a dynamically changing range of values from column E, starting at row 6, and paste into another worksheet (starting at column G row 15).  The numbers can be pasted as values.

Essentially, I would like the copy function to stop when the row becomes blank.

Pretty much a newbie with VBA but I have done some messing around with it.

Thanks!

Comment: Okay what is messing around? `VBA Code?` may we see it what have you tried so far, and where your attempt  fail?

Comment: Sorry for not posting what I had, I have never used this site and I am just breaking into some basic macro to help out my company.  From now on, I will post what I have attempted.  @Omar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow :)

```
Range("E6", Range("E" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Copy
Range("G" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
```

Looks confusing but this is what it means:

Range of E6 to bottom of the row Ctrl+Up arrow

Copy

Bottom of row G ctrl+up arrow then down one to the next blank

Paste

In future if you want help make sure to show enough detail to prove you have had a go and are not just wanting it written for you, that is what the comment above is on about.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! This is what I ended up figuring out prior to the answers:  

LastRow = Sheets("Prod Data Pivot").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

LastCol = Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column

Sheets("Prod Data Pivot").Range("E6:E" & LastRow).Copy

Sheets(1).Range("G15").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

@AndrewT

Comment: @jdahl32 no problem, so has that solved your problem? if so check the box otherwise let me know if I can help further.